# Getting a String from a value in Mysql in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

i have the following table in MySql :

```
ID          Name

1           Google
2           Yahoo
3           Facebook
4           Whatever
```

I have a textfield that when someone writes something and presses a button it stores this value in a string. This string is the Name of the above table. Then i have my code about selecting the id referred to that name. Ex, if the user enters Facebook i will find that the ID = 3. this is the code :

```
    public bool FindCompanyID(string companyName)
{
    return ExecQuery("select id from companies where name=@name",
        cmd =>
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id from companies WHERE name ='" + companyName + "'";
            return cmd;
        });
}
```

I want someone to show me a sample of code about the following : Saving to a string the " id " . if the ID in the database = 2 i want to make a

```
int Company_Number_ID
```

that i will use. How can i get the string to read the specified value from the database?

Comment: What library are you using to query the database ?

Comment: MySql Connector and it works fine so far, MySql.Data.6.9.9 ( i add and delete without any problem )

Comment: Your `ExecQuery` method returns a bool, you need to find a method in your API equivalent to `ExecuteScalar` in Microsoft libraries which returns a value from the executed query. That's why I'm asking what is the library.

Comment: Can you make me an example for this please?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing your return type is `bool` to check whether the `DDL` statements were executed successfully.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id from companies WHERE name ='" + companyName + "'";

try
{
    dbConn.Open();                
    Company_Number_ID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Exception occured. Handle it here
}
```

**Note:** `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyName",companyName)`.
this is more secure

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comment by `user3185569` , `ExecuteScalar` is better if you are sure it'll return only one row. But since no such information was provided. I did not consider that.

You can use `ExecuteScalar` directly like this.

```
Company_Number_ID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Isn't `ExecuteScalar` a better approach here than the reader ?

Comment: I did not want to assume what was not provided :( . What if the company name `Facebook` was mapped to two ID's. I know it's not how it might be, you know just in case

Comment: Can you guys show me what to do in ExecuteScalar? The values are unique and not null so it will work

Comment: I need to place the full code you gave me, just change the line that converts to int 32 to executeScalar?

Comment: @NeoEssence please see the answer now

Comment: Could you please check your facebook profile? I sent you a request if you can i would like you to guide me in a few steps. I am new to programing and i really could use some help and ask you some questions about it